# How can I link multiple view controllers to one container view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uicontainerview

I want to link multiple view controllers to one container view. I think if I do the linking process programmatically, that can be happen.

There are few buttons such as "Home", "Profile", "Settings" etc. And I want to change content of container view with using button label when user click one of these buttons. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Note: I can't change viewcontroller content that linked to container. Because there should be different types of viewcontroller for each button.(such as navigationvc, tableviewvc)

----Edited on request

There is a main VC. It has a sidebar on the left, and there is some buttons.  These buttons suppose to change the content of the container view. I didn't add any segue at storyboard because I can add just one. At this point I want to perform programmatically segue instead of easier way. So I can fill the content of container view with any view controller that I want. But I don't know how can I do it?

Sidebar buttons:

Homepage and Profile -> calls a different ViewController which will displayed by container

Setting, Messagges, Shop -> calls a different TableViewController which will displayed by container

Shortly, There is five buttons and each of them triggers different segues five different View Controllers. And there is just one container that display the View Controller which triggered.

I can change the anything except the sidebar. there have to be a sidebar.

Comment: I would suggest using a Tab Bar Controller for what it sounds like you're doing, and then you can use a different View Controller for each tab's view.

Comment: I developing this application for a friend and he didn't like that idea. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing the buttons you mention? Might give a better idea of where you want to go with it.

Comment: I explained more details as I could. But I did't add a screenshot because of my reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with using this code:

```
    var homeVC: homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! homeViewController           
    self.containerView.addSubview(homeVC.view)
    self.addChildViewController(homeVC)
```

I can explain more detailed if someone asks.

**UPDATE:**

I think the topic below explains more efficient way to do link multiple `view controllers` to one `container view`

https://kodesnippets.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/container-view-in-ios/

Comment: Hi Faruk, I'm trying to do the same thing as you. I had a working project in Obj C but can't seem to get it to work yet in swift. Could you show some more details? Thanks!

Comment: Hi BossBols, sorry for the big delay. I just saw your comment. If you need that details still, I can share.

Comment: Hey Faruk. I found a way to make it work about a month ago. The conversion took some thinking out of the box, swift can be weird!. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Yes, that's right. It can be weird sometimes. Really sorry for the delay again.

Comment: @Faruk the link you posted saved me a ton of frustration! thanks

Comment: I would be very happy, if I made your work a little bit less. @LanceSamaria

Comment: @Faruk  : Can you guys please post the final answer here. Even though BossBols found out his own solution or you have your own solution, still people like me are waiting for it. :P Can you please post your answers here.

Comment: Anyways Found answer on link which is what your above link also does:  http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Comment: @Faruk Please tell me That can I Add two VC in a container, And can I have focus on both simultanously. Eg: Wynk Music App :- There we have List of music as well music playing in different VC which can be expanded and collapsed.